# How to process an array in a Hive UDF in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a Scala UDF for Hive that accepts an Array of integers as an input parameter and returns the length of the array. Extending the UDF class, I'm able to create simple Hive UDFs that take int/string inputs, however the issue arrises when I try to input an Array/List to the UDF. Here is how to reproduce the issue:

1. Write the Scala UDF:

```
package HiveUDFs
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF

class ListLength extends UDF {
    def evaluate(list: List[Int]): Int = list.length
}
```

2. Package the jar and add it to spark-sql command.
3. Create a temporary function:

```
>CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION list_length AS 'HiveUDFs.ListLength';
```

4. Use the UDF:

```
>SELECT list_length(Array(1,2,3));
```

I get the following error:

```
No handler for UDF/UDAF/UDTF 'HiveUDFs.SumList': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.NoMatchingMethodException: No matching method for class HiveUDFs.SumList with (array<int>). Possible choices: _FUNC_(struct<>)  ; line 1 pos 7
```

I've used Seq instead of List as well and I get the same error.

I am able to achieve this using Java though with the ArrayList class:

```
package HiveUDFs;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class ListLength extends UDF {
    public int evaluate(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Since my project needs to be written in Scala, I really need to understand what type to use to accept arrays as a parameter for my UDF.